# Traversing divs selectively with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently traverse my divs to create the illusion of separate pages using jQuery like this:

```
function nextForm() {
    $(".Page:visible").hide( ).next( ".Page" ).show( );
}

function prevForm() {
    $(".Page:visible").hide( ).prev( ".Page" ).show( );
}
```

This is my main page where all the content is loaded:

```
<div class="Page" id="DealerInfo" style="display: block;">
    <script>$( "#DealerInfo" ).load( "formPages/DealerInfo.php" );</script>
</div>

<div class="Page" id="AdditionalLocations" style="display: none;">
    <script>$( "#AdditionalLocations" ).load( "formPages/AdditionalLocations.php" ); </script>
</div>

<div class="Page" id="OwnerInfo" style="display: none;">
    <script>$( "#OwnerInfo" ).load( "formPages/OwnerInfo.php" );</script>
</div>
```

This is just a small snippet of the main page. Now what I am looking to accomplish is; If a certain field on the form is equal to "1" I want to skip the `AdditionalLocations` div but if it is greater than "1" then I want it to show the "AdditionalLocations" div. I have tried  using `nextUntil('#OwnerInfo')` but it will still display the `AdditionalLocations` div. Can anyone dive me a solution to this?

Here is a j[sfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EpTwX/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a .not("#AdditionalLocationss") selector, and you must if else

Comment: What would that string look like it does not seem to be working ` $(".Page:visible").hide( ).next( ".Page" ).not("#AdditionalLocations").show( );
` it will not show the `OwnerInfo` div